# Writing to database fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have strange problems with my SQL query. I use wamp3 with PHP 7.0.7 and MySQL 5.7.11.

When I fill in a self-made form, and send it to another script that validates it, I get nothing back! There's something wrong, but I don't get any error message! MySQL is ok, it do not give an error! When I include the query below into PHPMyAdmin, the variables changed in strings and ints, of course, then it works well! Only the query below, in the PHP code fails! I don't know what happens.

I have contacted a friend and a Dutch forum, but the two don't know what the answer is!
The code I use is:

```
$sqlquery = "
    INSERT INTO 
        klanten 
            (
                naam, tussenv, achternaam, gebdat, 
                blindziend, email, wachtwoord, adres,
                busnr, postcode, postcodenlletters, woonplaats, 
                land, ontvfact, eigenOpm
            )
        VALUES 
            (
                $vnaam, $tussenv, $anaam, $gebdat, 
                $blindziend, $mail, $passw1, $adres, 
                $bus, $postcode, $postcnll, $city, 
                $country, $ontvfact, $eigenopm
            )
";

if(mysqli_query($sqlconnect, $sqlquery)) {
    echo "Alles is succesvol toegevoegd in onze database. U zal ongenblikkelijk
        terugkeren naar <a href='http://www.dikowork.com'>www.dikowork.com</a>.
        Bedankt voor uw inschrijving";
}
```

Does anybody have any solution?

Comment: 1.  Your query will fail if you have any string values being inserted (they need to be quoted).  2.  Your query will fail if your strings have quotes in them.  3.  Please use prepared statements.

Comment: You should add single qoutes arround string values. Better you learn about prepared statements

Comment: @nospor Please don't edit a post to make it incorrect! Does anybody have any solutions is correct, Does anybody has is not correct English.

Comment: @Styphon what are you talking about? I've just only added paragraphs and code formatting...

Comment: @nospor You changed `Does anybody have any solution` to `Does anybody has any solution? Thanks! Jordy.` according to the edit log.

Comment: @Styphon I wasn't changing any text. As I said, I've only added paragraphs and code formatting. I do not know why edit log show wrong data. Maybe author change sth while I was editing

Comment: @nospor Fair enough, probably SO getting itself confused with your and Jordy's edits.

Comment: Can you run `echo $sqlquery` and tell us what the output is?

Comment: So you have: "if OK then this". Just go one step forward and add "else do that" where that is e.g. retrieving and displaying the error message.

Comment: I got the query when i was echoing the sqlquery -variable! Thanks all! It is solved!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @Styphon: Actually, [nospor's edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12672808) was based off [Jordy Deweer's original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37792047/1) but was submitted just a few seconds after [Siyual had already cleaned it up](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37792047/2). There would have been a warning about the edit collision, but it can be easily overlooked or dismissed. Consequently, nospor's edit appeared (to reviewers such as yourself) to have rolled back some of Siyual's changes, such as the corrections to that closing line.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You must quoted all the strings example like $vnaam to '$vnaam'

```
$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO klanten 
    (naam, tussenv, achternaam, gebdat, blindziend, email, wachtwoord, adres,
    busnr, postcode, postcodenlletters, woonplaats, land, ontvfact, eigenOpm)
    VALUES ('$vnaam', '$tussenv', '$anaam', '$gebdat', '$blindziend', '$mail', '$passw1',
    '$adres', '$bus', '$postcode', '$postcnll', '$city', '$country', '$ontvfact', '$eigenopm')";
if(mysqli_query($sqlconnect, $sqlquery))
{
    echo "Alles is succesvol toegevoegd in onze database. U zal ongenblikkelijk
    terugkeren naar <a href='http://www.dikowork.com'>www.dikowork.com</a>.
    Bedankt voor uw inschrijving";
}
```

But its not an enough solutions. If one of your string has a quote it will fail.

For better solutions use Preperared Statements in PHP

Please look at this documents

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score -1):

There's probably the thing with quotes going here.
The best thing to do is using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with using this you don't have to worry about a thing.

```
$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO `klanten` 
    (`naam`, `tussenv`, `achternaam`, `gebdat`, `blindziend`, `email`, `wachtwoord`, `adres`,
    `busnr`, `postcode`, `postcodenlletters`, `woonplaats`, `land`, `ontvfact`, `eigenOpm`)
    VALUES ("'.$vnaam.'", "'.$tussenv.'", "'.$anaam.'", "'.$gebdat.'", "'.$blindziend.'", "'.$mail.'", "'.$passw1.'",
    "'.$adres.'", "'.$bus.'", "'.$postcode.'", "'.$postcnll.'", "'.$city.'", "'.$country.'", "'.$ontvfact.'", "'.$eigenopm.'")";
if(mysqli_query($sqlconnect, $sqlquery))
{
    echo "Alles is succesvol toegevoegd in onze database. U zal ongenblikkelijk
    terugkeren naar <a href='http://www.dikowork.com'>www.dikowork.com</a>.
    Bedankt voor uw inschrijving";
}
```

I've intrepreted everthing as a string right now, maybe you have some integer values too those can be without quotes

Comment: Converting to concatenation is bizarre and not necessary. It just introduces a ton of visual junk.